# SQL statement 4 table connect

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello currently i have 4 tables in my database: which are tb_student, tb_history, tb_section and tb_adviser. so far i used this line to show me the history of a given student:

```
   $qry_display = "SELECT
        a.student_id, a.section_id, a.level, a.photo, a.address, a.father_occupation, a.father_phone, a.father_company, a.mother_occupation, a.mother_phone, a.mother_company,a.gpa,
        b.fname, b.sex, b.lname, b.mname, b.birth_date, b.birth_place, b.address, b.father, b.father_degree, b.mother, b.mother_degree,
        c.section_name, c.adviser_id
        FROM tbl_er AS a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_enroll AS b ON a.student_id = b.student_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_section AS c ON a.section_id = c.section_id
        WHERE a.student_id=".$id." AND a.level='1st Year'";
```

my main problem is now i need to show the last name of the adviser with these other information. so i was thinking of putting. Note that tb_adviser is only CONNECTED to tb_section via adviser_id

```
     LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_adviser AS d ON a.student_id = c.adviser_id
```

I added this line before there where statement. and would insert this line in my SELECT fields.

```
     d.lname_adviser
```

Currently it doesn't work. Anyone would shed some light into my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing the db structure would help, but it looks like you are trying to have JOIN on two columns that won't match. Is a.student_id going to match c.adviser_id?

Assuming the advisor_id is id in tbl_advisor then just add

```
 LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_advisor AS d 
 ON d.id = c.advisor_id
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

I think you should do

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_adviser AS d ON d.adviser_id = c.adviser_id
```

So your query would be:

```
Select .....
FROM tbl_er AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_enroll AS b ON a.student_id = b.student_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_section AS c ON a.section_id = c.section_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_adviser AS d ON d.adviser_id = c.adviser_id 
WHERE a.student_id=".$id." AND a.level='1st Year'
```